# how to hide scrollbar without overflow: hidden

Tags: scroll, scrollbar, overflow, vertical-scrolling

So as far as I'm concerned, overflow:hidden does hide the scrollbar, but makes it impossible to scroll (at least scrolling doesn't work in Firefox).

I have a scroller-slider on my homepage - it scrolls automaticaly to lower full-screen elements one by one and then comes back to the first element and starts over. It looks really nice in my opinion, but the scrollbar is visible - I would like to make it invisible. With overflow: hidden the scrolling mechanism doesn't work.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Anybody? I've been trying to figure it out since yesterday and for now I'm really out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide scrollbar with CSS - wrap your scrollable container into another one with `overflow:hidden` and less height/width (depending on scroll you want to hide - vertical or horizontal one). This way helps if you have static container/content sizes. If container can be resized or size depends on content - you will have to use JS solution to calculate container size.