# Hide scrollbars in div cross-browser without breaking overflow text

Tags: html, css

**The setup:**
Midway down a page I'm building I have some super-sized text inside a div which I'd like to be scrollable. The text should run off the right-hand edge of the screen, and be only horizontally scrollable (I'll hook up sideways scrolling afterwards if I can get this looking correct first).

I need to hide the scrollbars (currently I get 0, or 1, or 2!). I have it working in chrome, but in Firefox, Safari, and IE the scrollbars still appear.

I found [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008872/hiding-scrollbar-in-div), [and this one which looks promising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22473799/how-to-hide-scrollbar-without-overflow-hidden), and this [codepen example](https://codepen.io/JonAnderDev/pen/XJNOPr) which does exactly what I want it to, but when I tried to apply it to my own code it hid the overflowing text (it looks as though the trick is to hide the overflowing scrollbar with a container but I can't work out how to do it whilst keeping my text visibly overflowing to the right).

Here's my example code taken out context:

```
  .outer_container {
      padding-top: 3rem;
      padding-left: 15px;
      margin-bottom: 5rem;
  }

  .middle_container{
      overflow-x:scroll;
      white-space:nowrap;
      width: 100%;
      padding-top: 1rem;
  }

  #inner_container {
      display:inline-block;
      padding-bottom: 2rem;
      overflow-x: scroll;
  }

  h1 {
      font-size: 12rem;
      line-height: 10rem;
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }

  /* WORKS IN CHROME, SIMILAR THING FOR OTHER BROWSERS WITHOUT BREAKING TEXT OVERFLOW? */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: none;
  }
```

```
<div class="outer_container">

    <div class="middle_container">

        <div id="inner_container">

            <h1>Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Cras mattis consectetur.</h1>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated, I'm sure the solution is in the codepen, I'm just very new to this and struggling to see what I'm doing wrong when implementing it in my own page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
...

.middle_container{
    white-space:nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#inner_container {
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

...
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgXXaX

Comment: Aah cracking, on a first look this appears to be working. I'll try it in-situ this evening. Thank you!

Comment: not working if box-sizing is border-box. anyhow it helped. thanks :-)